# Redefinition of wrindex and @indexfile

Tags: imakeidx

I'm working with big book and there is a redefinition of `@wrindex`, and after i added package `imakeidx` it stopped work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
 \protected@write{\@indexfile}{}{%
   #1% some additional code goes here
   :\thepage
 }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\index{notepad}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

With this minimalistic example i got the following error:

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \@indexfile 
>                     l.16 \index{
>         notepad}
> ```

But i need to use `imakeidx`.

Comment: Untested (I have no access to LaTeX right now: `\AtBeginDocument{\def\@wrindex#1{....}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it doesn't work. Could you give a suggestion in what direction i may look for?

Comment: No, I have no sources etc. at hand and can't suggest anything other what I have done above -- it was a guess only.

Comment: With `imakeidx`, `\@wrindex` expects *two* arguments. With your setup, the macro to patch is `\imki@wrindexentrysplit`. And `\@indexfile` is obviously undefined, because `imakeidx` is set up to prepare several indices. If you add some details about the “additional code”, maybe we can help more.

Comment: @egreg thanks sir, i got it 30 seconds ago:) playing with imakeidx.sty. Thanks a lot!